# Disable UIScrollView scrolling when UITextField becomes first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

When a `UITextField` embedded in a `UIScrollView` becomes the first responder (for example, by the user typing in some character), the `UIScrollView` scrolls to that Field automatically. Is there any way to disable that?

[Duplicate rdar://16538222](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Are you using a `UIViewController` or a `UITableViewController`? For the latter, it's the standard and normally wanted behavior.

Comment: Well, I am using UITextField embedded in a UIScrollView. I am simulating the SMS app "To" Field, so whenever the user types a letter, I am scrolling to the line being edited (by setting the contentOffset of the UIScrollView) - Like in Three20 if you know it. What is happening is that when a user types a letter, the UIScrollView scrolls to the editing line, making the UITextField's origin beyond the contentSize of the scrollView, THen when the user types another letter, it is scrolling back up to the origin of the UITextField (default behavior of SCrollView), so i get this up and down behavior

Comment: I agree, there should be a way to disable it manually, but I can't find it either.  I find myself fighting the scrolling system because of this behavior.

Answer (score 64):

Building on [Moshe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586207/14351818)... Subclass `UIScrollView` and override the following method:

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Leave it empty. Job done!

---

In Swift:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool) { }
}
```

Comment: This solution is mentioned here: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/94288-disabling-uiscrollview-autoscroll.html

Comment: Simple and elegant solution.  Cheers!!

Comment: This means the ScrollRectToVisible method will be unusable if you wish to do anything manually with it. A nice solution if you don't want to do that though.

Comment: I start receiving "CALayer bounds contains NaN" error reports on Firebase after using this workaround.

Answer (score 60):

I've been struggling with the same problem, and at last I've found a solution.

I've investigated how the auto-scroll is done by tracking the call-trace, and found that an internal `[UIFieldEditor scrollSelectionToVisible]` is called when a letter is typed into the `UITextField`. This method seems to act on the `UIScrollView` of the nearest ancestor of the `UITextField`.

So, on `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, by wrapping the `UITextField` with a new `UIScrollView` with the same size of it (that is, inserting the view in between the `UITextField` and it's superview), this will block the auto-scroll. Finally remove this wrapper on `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

The code goes like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {  
    UIScrollView *wrap = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:textField.frame] autorelease];  
    [textField.superview addSubview:wrap];  
    [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)]; 
    [wrap addSubview: textField];  
}  

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField {  
  UIScrollView *wrap = (UIScrollView *)textField.superview;  
  [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(wrap.frame.origin.x, wrap.frame.origin.y, wrap.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
  [wrap.superview addSubview:textField];  
  [wrap removeFromSuperview];  
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note: textFieldDidBeginEditing should be textFieldShouldBeginEditing otherwise it works fine

Comment: +1 not the cleanest of solutions , but certainly guides in the proper direction :)

Comment: Oh my gosh. Taketo, THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! And Rabih, THANKS SO MUCH FOR ASKING! I would never have figured this out. I'd give this 100 upvotes if I could.

Comment: Win! This has been troubling me all week (and, in earlier versions of this project, for over a year). Thanks. As noted in other comments, I found it simpler to leave the textfield *always* wrapped in a UIScrollView of the same size -- swapping the views in and out isn't necessary.

Comment: Does this work for anyone using iOS 5.1? I can't seem to get the trick to work!

Comment: How can you use textField.origin? Wouldn't you have to use textField.frame.origin??

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with disabling auto-scrolling of a `UITextView` being a cell of `UITableView`. I was able to resolve it using the following approach:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITextViewDelegate>

@implementation MyTableViewController {
    BOOL preventScrolling;
    // ...
}

// ... set self as the delegate of the text view

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    preventScrolling = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (preventScrolling) {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    preventScrolling = NO;
}
```

Defining `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is used for restoring the default scrolling behaviour, when the user himself initiates scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for sharing // this worked well - Other solution for this question to inject scroll view didn't work for me given the project constraints - Much appreciated

Comment: this just keeps the view scroll stuck to top

Answer (score 8):

As Taketo mentioned, when a `UITextField` is made first responder, its first parent view that is of type `UIScrollView` (if one exists) is scrolled to make that `UITextField` visible. The easiest hack is to simply wrap each UITextField in a `UIScrollView` (or ideally, wrap all of them in a single dummy `UIScrollView`). This is very similar to Taketo's solution, but it should give you slightly better performance, and it will keep your code (or your interface in Interface Builder) much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: It worked for me using the [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). Thanks!

Comment: Great work around! We can use a contentView to hold textFields, this contentView should be scrollView but not scrollable.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Luke's answer, to handle the issue that his solution completely disables auto-scroll, you can disable it selectively as follows:

```
//  TextFieldScrollView
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextFieldScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable BOOL preventAutoScroll;

@end

@implementation TextFieldScrollView

- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.preventAutoScroll == NO) {
        [super scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:animated];
    }
}

@end
```

This way, you can completely set it up in Interface Builder to disable the auto-scroll, but have full control at any time to re-enable it (though why you'd want to is beyond me).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like UIScrollview which contains UITextfield, auto adjusts its content offset; when textfield is going to become first responder.
This can be solved by adding textfield in scrollview of same size first, and then adding in to main scroll view. instead of directly adding in to main scrollview

```
    // Swift

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)

    let txtfld = UITextField()
    txtfld.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)

    let txtFieldContainerScrollView = UIScrollView()
    txtFieldContainerScrollView.frame = rect
    txtFieldContainerScrollView.addSubview(txtfld)
    // Now add this txtFieldContainerScrollView in desired UITableViewCell, UISCrollView.. etc
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(txtFieldContainerScrollView)

    // Am33T
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it:

It is very simple, you get to return your own contentOffset for any scrollRectToVisible.

This way you are not harming the normal behaviour and flow of things - just providing the same functionality in the same channel, with your own improvements.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ExtendedScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (CGPoint)scrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView offsetForScrollingToVisibleRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end

@interface ExtendedScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<ExtendedScrollViewDelegate> scrollToVisibleDelegate;

@end

#import "ExtendedScrollView.h"

@implementation ExtendedScrollView

- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (_scrollToVisibleDelegate && [_scrollToVisibleDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView:offsetForScrollingToVisibleRect:)])
    {
        [self setContentOffset:[_scrollToVisibleDelegate scrollView:self offsetForScrollingToVisibleRect:rect] animated:animated];
    }
    else
    {
        [super scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:animated];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any property of `UIScrollView` that would allow that. It would be poor user experience to be able to disable that, IMHO.

That said, it may be possible to subclass `UIScrollView` and override some of its methods to check that the `UITextfield` is not a first responder before scrolling.

Comment: it didn't work, can you please see my comment to Ortwin's answer for some detail?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried @TaketoSano's answer, but seems not works.. My case is that I don't have a scrollview, just a view with several text fields.

And finally, I got a workaround. There're two default notification names for keyboard that I need:

- `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` when the keyboard did show;
- `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` when the keyboard will hide.

Here's the sample code I used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  ...

  NSNotificationCenter * notificationCetner = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [notificationCetner addObserver:self
                         selector:@selector(_keyboardWasShown:)
                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                           object:nil];
  [notificationCetner addObserver:self
                         selector:@selector(_keyboardWillHide:)
                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                           object:nil];
}

- (void)_keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)note {
  [self.view setFrame:(CGRect){{272.f, 55.f}, {480.f, 315.f}}];
}

- (void)_keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
  [self.view setFrame:(CGRect){{272.f, 226.5f}, {480.f, 315.f}}];
}
```

Here, the `(CGRect){{272.f, 226.5f}, {480.f, 315.f}}` is view's default frame when keyboard is hidden. And `(CGRect){{272.f, 55.f}, {480.f, 315.f}}` is view's frame when keyboard did show.

And b.t.w., the view's frame changing will be applied animation automatically, this's really perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I have a collection view with a text field at the very top, mimicking the `UITableView.tableHeaderView`. This text field is located in the negative content offset space so that it doesn't interfere with the rest of the collection view. I basically am detecting whether or not the user is performing the scrolling in the scroll view and whether or not the text field is first responder and if the scroll view is being scrolled beyond the top of the scroll view's content inset. This exact code won't necessarily help anyone but they could manipulate it to fit their case.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // This is solving the issue where making the text field first responder
    // automatically scrolls the scrollview down by the height of the search bar.
    if (!scrollView.isDragging && !scrollView.isDecelerating &&
        self.searchField.isFirstResponder &&
        (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -scrollView.contentInset.top)) {

        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, -scrollView.contentInset.top) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

An easier way to stop the scrollview scrolling when you select a textField is in your viewController::viewWillAppear() DO NOT call [super viewWillAppear];

You can then control the scroll as you wish.

Comment: You're going to introduce _a lot_ of weird behaviour to your app by not calling the superclass implementation here. I'd advise against doing it.