# How do I stop a UIScrollView from automatically scrolling when a UITextField is touched out of the scrollview's frame?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield

By default, if a textfield is a child of a scrollview and is touched when it is partially outside of the frame of the parent scrollview, the scrollview scrolls up a little. For example, let's say we have a scroll view with a frame height of 200, but a contentSize height of 260 and we put a text field at position 220. Now I scroll up and position the textfield half inside of the scrollview's frame and let the other half get cut off. If I touch this textfield, I notice that the scrollview automatically scrolls up by a couple pixels before the keyboard comes up. This is problematic because I already have my own scrolling code, so when this happens, it ends up scrolling twice as far as I want it to. Is there any way to remove this default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your scrollview is getting moved in response to the keyboard showing instead of the text field being tapped. Take a look at [Apple's Managing the Keyboard documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html); it has a helpful section on scrollviews.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question already has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5673026/550177

You can also try to reset the scrollview's contentOffset when the textfield becomes first responder. Implemement the text field delegate like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:_scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

This code removes that automatic animation when the textfield is selected. I've tested with iOS 6.1 in the simulator.