# UIScrollView scrolled after setContentSize

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

So I want to create some detail content in UIView(320,470) that taller than Viewport (320, 367).

I create it separated in IB like (see pic.). Everything looks OK until I setContentSize to make the UIScrollView scrollable..

This is my code placed in `ViewDidLoad`

```
CGRect frame = self.uiContent.frame;
[self.uiScrollView addSubview:self.uiContent];
[self.uiScrollView setContentSize:frame.size];
```

The content is scrolled with animation to middle after setContentSize is called.. How to prevent that auto-scroll?

[image]

Comment: don't know but you can try     [uiScrollView scrollsToTop] after that

Comment: did you try addSubview after setContentSize, is it same of different??

Comment: I already try that... scrollsToTop, change the sequence and do both... No luck...

Comment: what about setContentOffset and scrollRectToVisible ??

Comment: still no luck... I think `setContentSize` call something that cause the ScrollView geting scrolled.. But It is no scrolled if I add simple `UIView` with color.. weird thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit.. It was `UITextView`. Sorry if I don't mention I use UITextView for multiline label under address label.

Quoting "Taketo Sano" on other question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5673026/453407

> I've investigated how the auto-scroll is done by tracking the
>   call-trace, and found that an internal [UIFieldEditor
>   scrollSelectionToVisible] is called when a letter is typed into the
>   UITextField. This method seems to act on the UIScrollView of the
>   nearest ancestor of the UITextField.

`UIScrollView` is auto scrolled to `UITextView` when `UITextView` text is changed. So I found the solution by subclassing `UIScrollview` and override

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
```

and return nothing to disable the auto scroll... If you plan to use it in future, just use a bool variable to enable / disable it by using

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!self.disableAutoScroll) {
        [super scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:animated];
    }
}
```

so you can disable the autoscroll before you change the UITextView by code and enable it after.