# iPhone - UITextView changes position when edited

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I've created a textView in this way:

```
UITextView*txtview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,25,25)];
txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtview.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
txtview.inputView = segmentKB;
txtview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:txtview];
[txtview sizeToFit];
```

My problem is that when I edit this text view, it moves up of some pixels.

How can I solve this and why does it happen?
The inputView is a segmented control, but the same problem also happens with a normal keyboard.

Comment: have a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585718/disable-uiscrollview-scrolling-when-uitextfield-becomes-first-responder

Comment: It's because of your `autoResizing` constraints for your `txtView`. Check it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change height of txtview from 25 to 35.

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing to do with setting up any property,its been developed likewise by apple's engineer.Use UITextField instead of UITextView or increase the height of UITextView atleast 2-3 lines in height.

**EDIT**: You can create your own custom textview(as required by you) by subclassing it.Because UITextView itself is a subclass of UIScrollView.Create a subclass of UITextView's method called - (UIEdgeInsets) contentInset;(make it return UIEdgeInsetsZero).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the clear button appearing from the right side of the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sizeTofit` which automatically adjust the rect and font of textview..