# Preventing autoscroll with UITextView embedded in UIScrollView on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7, uitextview

I've been using the technique of wrapping a UITextField in a UIScrollView to prevent autoscrolling, for details on this, see this discussion on SO:

[Disable UIScrollView scrolling when UITextField becomes first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585718/disable-uiscrollview-scrolling-when-uitextfield-becomes-first-responder)

This has been working fine for some time now on iOS versions < 7.  However, it no longer seems to work on iOS 7. Has anybody else encountered this? Has anybody found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was happening ... I had code that was setting the contentOffset.y to 0.0f in certain cases ... but on iOS 7, that was causing the scroll view to scroll up too far, and it should be setting it to -64.0f.  I mistakenly thought this was being caused by UIScrollView's autoscrolling behavior.