# UIScrollView behaves differently after UITableView has been selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've been trying to fix this issue all day but can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. I have a UIScrollView which has a UITableView and numerous UITextFields as subviews. When I click the UITextField the UIScrollView will adjust it's contentOffset so the textfield appears above the keyboard. This all works fine until I click on the UITableView and select a cell, after this the UIScrollView performs an extra check and scrolls down about 50 pixels after the first contentOffset change. This is hard to explain so I have attached a video here which demonstrates what happens:

http://tinypic.com/r/14xj6gn/8

Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out the reason it happens. If anyone needs help then read this post here:

[Disable UIScrollView scrolling when UITextField becomes first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585718/disable-uiscrollview-scrolling-when-uitextfield-becomes-first-responder)