# Why UICollectionView offset changes when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app, that has a horizontal `UICollectionView`. Each of the cells has a `UITextField`. When the `UITextField` becomes first responder, the keyboard automatically comes up, and surprisingly all the cells move upwards.

I haven't implemented any logic for the cells to move upwards. Do you know why?

I haven't found any documentation regarding this, and I'm unable to fix this.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue and I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is implemented by Apple. The standard `UICollectionView` takes care for you to scroll to the correct position if a keyboard appears. Why would you want to fix this?

Comment: Because the animation is not the one we want. i need to customise the animation. Can I do so?

Comment: @user1447414 I'm not sure if you can. See here something similar, maybe this approach helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585718/disable-uiscrollview-scrolling-when-uitextfield-becomes-first-responder

Comment: @FabioBerger: Is this behaviour even applicable for UITextView?

Comment: @AnoopNyati Yes it should, since this behaviour is controlled by the UICollectionView, and not the UITextField.