# How to modify the UICollectionView animation with the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, uicollectionview

The standard behaviour when a cell contains a text field and becomes first responder, is automatically set the collection view's content offset to prevent the text field to be hidden.

[Why UICollectionView offset changes when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289078/why-uicollectionview-offset-changes-when-keyboard-appears/34289261#34289261)

This happens automatically and it's an expected behaviour.

How can I customise the animation of the cell going up, when the keyboard comes up?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

with this u can toggle UICollectionView height accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should implement UIScrollViewDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate and add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{    
   [self addNotificationObserver];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self removeObservers];

}


 -(void)addNotificationObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                              name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                            object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
 }

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                    CGRect f = self.view.frame;
                    f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
                    self.view.frame = f;
                }];
  }

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                    CGRect f = self.view.frame;
                    f.origin.y = 0.0f;
                    self.view.frame = f;
                }];
}

-(void)removeObservers 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: have you tested this with a UICollectionView and a UITextField in the cell?

Comment: I had a close look to your answer and it sets the view that holds the collectionview. I think this can work yes. But my question is more about how to access the animations details and modify them