# Why UIScrollView does not scroll up when UITextView becomes first responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

`UITextView` becomes first responder when user taps on a button to add a `UITextView` on `UIScrollView`. Actually UIView which contains `UITextView` or `UITextField` is added in `UIScrollView`. When keyboard appears, scrollview does not scroll up, however `UITextField` makes it scrolling up when it becomes first responder. I register `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to scroll up. Below is my code

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
        CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
        [(notification.userInfo)[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

        NSInteger height = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardEndFrame);

        NSInteger lastObj = arrayTotalObjects.count - 1;
        UIView *lastView = [arrayTotalObjects objectAtIndex:lastObj];

        if(!(lastView.frame.origin.y > height))
            return;

        UIEdgeInsets inset = originalInset;
        inset.bottom += height;
        NSLog(@"inset: %f", inset.bottom);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            scrlView.contentInset = inset;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"scrlView inset bottom: %f", scrlView.contentInset.bottom);
        }];
}
```

In this case lastView will be UIView containing UITextView.

This code works for `UITextField` but not for `UITextView`. How is that possible? Is it because `UITextView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

If someone see this question, The answer is set `UITextView scrolling enabled` **`false`**

In `lawicko`'s answer, I got a hint. `subclass of UIScrollView`.

It works to me.

Answer (score -2):

In short, the answer to your question is yes, this behavior is caused by UITextView being a subclass of UIScrollView. You can find more details, as well as the solution how to disable it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5673026/703809).

Comment: Downvoted because:
1. This wasn't a yes/no question
2. The referenced link doesn't have the solution either.